# Fixture.page doesn't change when the second file is starting in testcafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have multiple testcafe files , each have a starting page , While running all files together , Fixture.Page doesn't change for the second file , it still taking the first file page url

```html
//////// First fixture in the first file.

fixture('create-TestFixture1').disablePageReloads.page(PageObject.createNavigateUrl + '/TestFixture1')
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t
      .maximizeWindow();
  });
  
  
  
  
 //////// First fixture in the second file.
fixture('create-TestFixture2').disablePageReloads.page(PageObject.createNavigateUrl + '/TestFixture2')
  .beforeEach(async t => {
    await t
      .maximizeWindow();
  });
  
  
*Both files are in the same folder, so when running testcafe for this folder, when the first file finished succesfully and the second file start , the fixture for second file doesn't update the page url, it redirects to " 'PageObject.createNavigateUrl + '/TestFixture1' " , not  "'PageObject.createNavigateUrl + '/TestFixture2' ".
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with a simple reproducible example? Make sure that you use the latest TestCafe version.

Comment: @VladimirA. , I have added an example for the fixtures , and I am using latest version.

Comment: How was this solved?

Answer (score 1):

The `disablePageReloads` feature is undocumented and experimental. It's subject to change. At the moment, I see no workaround for this multiple fixtures case. You can only split your two `disablePageReloads` fixtures into two TestCafe runs: `testcafe fixture-1.js` and `testcafe fixture-2.js`.

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir , the issue is not with disablePageReloads  , I removed it. the issue is that the second fixture's page doesn't updated , it keeps navigating to the first fixture's page url

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this issue without using `disablePageReloads`. I suppose you may have accidentally overridden your tested page in some [`Test.page`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/test/page.html) method. Please share your complete example that uses public URLs.